# Special characters

Tags: 2013-sp1, encoding

I'm trying to write special characters in Page Metadata, in title and description. There are String Text in their schema.

When I write "&" and I preview de page, this symbol changes and I see "&". If I try write "&", when I preview, this symbol changes and I see "&amp;". Anybody can help me?

In the other hand, the editor is trying to write some symbols like checks or arrows in this fields. When I preview, this symbols show correctly, but when I publish the page, this symbols change and show in the source page something like this "[image]"

We are using:

- SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1
- Target publication are configurated as UTF-8
- Tomcat also are configurated as UTF-8

Comment: And if you use these characters in Rich Text, they show fine? Could be in how the fields are handled in TOM.NET (StringTextField vs XhtmlTextField)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is related to output type of your template. By default, if your template output is Text/HTML, then by default, all of special characters will get HTML encoded so that they don't break HTML layout. Same is with following signs: < > & copyright sign etc....

If I am not mistaken this is done by [Default finish actions compound template](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-EF142CAA-A9EB-4B8C-862F-7D70135ED879&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-EF142CAA-A9EB-4B8C-862F-7D70135ED879.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-EF142CAA-A9EB-4B8C-862F-7D70135ED879&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DConvert%2520Xml%2520to%2520Html&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1530001840749&currentQuery=Convert%2520Xml%2520to%2520Html&currentScope=).
What you can try to do, is remove some of the blocks related to tidying HTML, or write placeholder for these signs, and later rewriting them after Default Finish actions.

Comment: Ok, thank you, we are going to try to control it in DFA.

Comment: What ever approach we try Title and description in HTML supports simple texts only, not special characters.